# Prototyping style, colors, feel, CSS for a web application

Tags: jquery, css, themes, stylesheet, prototyping

Well we are running a pretty old fashioned looking web application. No fancy animations from jquery and the design is basically done with one color.
My goal is now to create a better looking application, rearranging things, introducing new effects, new colors, new feel. But just as prototype, it does not have to be perfect - just to get the idea. Maybe give several different suggestions as well - I finally have to present it to the customer and he/she says yes/no.

Basically what I am doing now is throwing out all the stuff which is in my way and then I fiddle around with the CSS - which is very time consuming to get everything aligned nicely again.

Is there a tool/smart approach which would support me in doing this?
Maybe a framework which already has some built in themes I can just apply to some of my pages?

Comment: did u check the http://jqueryui.com/ ?

Comment: If your job is to create a new look and feel for the web application, then your prototype should be built in Photoshop. Don't get into the code until everything in the actual design has been approved, or you'll just end up building everything twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all depends on how well formatted the web application currently is.

Does it use CSS classes? Then it might be quite easy to change the current styles to reflect the new look and feel.

Or you could use things like Chrome's Inspect Element to quickly update the colors and fonts and positioning and then make a screenshot.

Comment: I started with photoshop - but hey i'm a developer. I had very hard time doing small things there - and on a later stage changin e.g. the look of all button colors - no way. I ended up using jQuery UI Themeroller which seems to have a good approach to how to get a consistent look through the application.

Answer (score 1):

Try mocking up the new design in photoshop, then upload that to something like invision ( http://www.invisionapp.com/ ) to prototype the interactivity.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd be tempted to try and convey the L & F of the application without needing to knock anything up in code, perhaps with some of the many wireframing tools.

This way you can positiong elements simply and give the impression of the design without committing the time needed to code anything.